# Efficiently merge two arrays by distribute values evenly

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

I have seen many question/answer subject to merge two array by alternating Values. they are working like this:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = [1, 2];

let outcome = ["a",1 ,"b", 2, "c", "d"]
```

but i want output to be more efficient with even distribution of value based on array size.

```
expected outcome = ["a","b", 1, "c", "d", 2]
```

other scenario

```
let array2 = [1];
expected outcome = ["a","b", 1, "c", "d"]
```

what should be the best way to achieve this sort of merging?

Comment: The first and second scenario are not consistent. Why does the first one end with `2` and not something like `["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", "d"]`

Comment: For the arrays `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` and `[1, 2]`, does it become `[a, b, c, 1, d, e, f, 2]` or `[a, b, 1, c, d, 2, e, f]`?

Comment: @adiga thats what the question is all about. i want values to be evenly merged. you said why not ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", "d"], its because value 1 and 2 is immediately merged with first array one after the another and there are more elements stay behind "c","d". it should be evenly placed as per the ratio between sizes of two array.

Comment: What about the second comment? Would it become `[a, b, c, 1, d, e, f, 2]` or `[a, b, 1, c, d, 2, e, f]` and why?

Comment: @adiga answer to your question. For the arrays [a, b, c, d, e, f] and [1, 2], does it become [a, b, c, 1, d, e, f, 2] or [a, b, 1, c, d, 2, e, f]?
I DON"T MIND RESULT [a, b, c, 1, d, e, f, 2] or [a, b, 1, c, d, 2, e, f] AS LONG AS VALUES ARE EVENLY PLACED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the ratio of the two arrays' lengths, `longest.length/shortest.length` and then take that many from the longest for every one in the shortest.

```js
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
let array2 = [1, 2];

const evenDistribute = (array1, array2) => {
  const longest = array1.length > array2.length ? array1 : array2;
  const shortest = array1.length > array2.length ? array2 : array1;
  const ratio = Math.floor(longest.length / shortest.length);
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < shortest.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < ratio; j++) {
      results.push(longest[i * ratio + j]);
    }
    results.push(shortest[i]);
  }
  // Grab any that are left over
  for (let i = longest.length - (longest.length % shortest.length); i < longest.length; i++) {
    results.push(longest[i]);
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(evenDistribute(array1, array2));
```

Comment: OP can write the edge case for sticking a single item in the middle of the array

Comment: @AdrianBrand your answer seems working fine. testing with different inputs. i don't mind the position of the element in the array if there is only one exist.

Answer (score 2):

This function was influenced by adiga's answer but handles the distribution a little better by calculating the insert index based on a decimal interval instead of `Math.ceil`.

It also avoids mutating the input arrays by creating a copy of the long array before inserting the short array's data.

If you find any cases that it doesn't cover let me know :)

```js
function mergeAndDistributeArrays(array1, array2) {
  // Find the long/short arrays based on length
  const [long, short] =
    array1.length >= array2.length ? [array1, array2] : [array2, array1];

  // Calculate the interval
  const interval = long.length / (short.length + 1);

  // Copy the long array so we don't mutate the input arrays
  const merged = [...long];

  // Iterate the short array and insert the values into the long array
  short.forEach((value, index) => {
    // Calculate the insert index based on the interval and the current index
    const insertAt = Math.ceil(interval * (index + 1));

    // Insert the value
    merged.splice(insertAt + index, 0, value);
  });

  return merged;
}

console.log(
  mergeAndDistributeArrays(
    [1,2,3],
    ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to find out per how many items of the long array you will have to mix an item from the short array. The code below is to demonstrate the concept. Maybe you will have to adjust it a little bit for all edge scenarios.

```js
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = [1, 2];


//Get the long and short arrays and calc the length factor
var [longArray, shortArray] = array1.length >= array2.length ? [array1, array2] : [array2, array1];
let lengthFactor = longArray.length / shortArray.length;


var c = 0
let smallIdx = 0;
let result = longArray.flatMap(item => {

  c++;
  
  if (c % lengthFactor === 0) {
    return [item, shortArray[smallIdx++]]
  }
  else
    return [item];    
})


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looking at OPs comment, it looks that the samples are not expected to be met accurately and they just there for providing hints. 

So, I believe, rather than the exact code, OP gets the idea behind the implementation. 

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could get the interval for distribution. Then loop through the second array and use `splice` to update the specific indices of the first array.

```js
function distribute(original, replace) {
  const interval = Math.ceil(original.length / (replace.length + 1));
  replace.forEach((r, i) => original.splice(interval * (i + 1) + i, 0, r))
  console.log(...original)
}

distribute(["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1])
distribute(["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1, 2])
distribute(["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1, 2, 3])
distribute(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], [1, 2])
distribute(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: `const a = 'a'.repeat(15).split('')`
`distribute(a, 'b'.repeat(15).split('')) => a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b`
`distribute(a, 'b'.repeat(13).split('')) => a a b a a b a a b a a b a a b a a b a a b a b b b b b b`

And if you replace 15 by 250 and 13 by 248, the result is way worse

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let array2 = [1, 2];

function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    let newArr1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    let newArr2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));
    [newArr1, newArr2] = newArr1.length >= newArr2.length ? [newArr1, newArr2] : [newArr2, newArr1];
    const interval = newArr1.length / newArr2.length;
    newArr2.map((item, index) => {
        newArr1.splice(interval * (index + 1), 0, item);
    })
    return newArr1;
}
console.log(merge(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mix = (firstArray, secondArray) => {
    const itrArray = firstArray.length > secondArray.length ? firstArray : secondArray;
    const result = [];

    for(let i=0; i<itrArray.length; i++){
        firstArray[i] && result.push(firstArray[i]);
        secondArray[i] && result.push(secondArray[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(mix([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]));
// [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
console.log(mix(["h", "a", "c"], [7, 4, 17, 10, 48]));
// ["h", 7, "a", 4, "c", 17, 10, 48]
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.