# distribution of values from 2 arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to find a way to distribute 2 arrays equally for example I got

```
let a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
let b = [0,0,0,0]

function distrubute(a, b){
//I need help with this function

 return ?
}

let distributed = distribute()

console.log(distributed)
// [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]

// this one has to be true:
console.log(distributed.length === a.length)
```

Comment: Does the order from the array matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently merge two arrays by distribute values evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888437/efficiently-merge-two-arrays-by-distribute-values-evenly)

Comment: I think that this is what you look for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888478/5356216

Comment: @vladc no the order doesnt really matter

Comment: @ZoltánSüle no this is not the same as what i need but thanks !

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure the first parameter is the bigger array
2. calculate ratio between two arrays
3. iterate them both, if the iteration index is divided by (ratio + 1) with remainder -> pick a value from the bigger array, else -> pick a value from the smaller array.

Original question answer:

```js
const a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
const b = [0, 0, 0, 0]

function distrubute(a, b) {
  if (a.length < b.length) return distribute(b, a);
  const distributed = [];
  const ratio = a.length / b.length;
  let iA = 0,
    iB = 0;
  while (iA + iB < a.length) {
    distributed.push((iA + iB) % (ratio + 1) > 0 ? a[iA++] : b[iB++]);
  }
  return distributed;
}
const distributed = distrubute(a, b);
console.log(distributed);
```

Edited question answer:

```js
const a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
const b = [0, 0, 0, 0]

function distrubute(a, b) {
  if (a.length < b.length) return distribute(b, a);
  const distributed = [];
  const ratio = a.length / b.length;
  let iA = 0,
    iB = 0;
  while (iA + iB < a.length + b.length) {
    distributed.push((iA + iB) % (ratio + 1) > 0 ? a[iA++] : b[iB++]);
  }
  return distributed;
}
const distributed = distrubute(a, b);
console.log(distributed);
```

Comment: the length of the output array has the wrong length it is not a.length + b.length do you know why this is ?

Comment: Hey @jaapklaas you asked `[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]`, if you want `[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]` just change `while` condition from `iA + iB < a.length` to `iA + iB < a.length + b.length`

Comment: im sorry but now its pushing a lot undefined at the end of the array when the  length some bigger

Comment: if the length of a = 931 and the length of b =311 
its pushing a lot undefined

Comment: hey @jaapklaas why `a.length` is 931 and not 933?

Answer (score 1):

May another short way

```
function distribute(a, b) {
    const distance = a.length / b.length + 1;
    return a.map((val, index) => {
        if (index % distance === 0) { return b[index / distance]; }
        else { return val; }
    });
}
// 0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0

function distribute(a, b) {
    const distance = a.length / b.length;
    return a.flatMap((val, index) => {
        if (index % distance === 0) { return [b[index / distance], val]; }
        else { return val; }
    });
}
// 0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: thanks so much but also from this one the length of the output array has the wrong length it is not a.length + b.length do you know why this is?

Comment: This is just an example how you can fit one array into another. I updated the comment. So now the first example should fit it like you expected in your question and the second how to fit without loss of any characters.

Comment: if the length of a = 931 and the length of b =311 
console.log(distributed.length === a.length + b.length)
is false